# Cannot export Sketch file to Zeplin. Forbidden 403 Error

Tags: sketch-3, zeplin

I am new to both Sketch and Zeplin.

When I am exporting my artboard by pressing cmd + E everything seems to be fine.

Zeplin prompts me to select a project. When I select a project to export into, I get a notification saying "Exported 1 screen(s) to ProjectName".

However a short time later it gives me a error dialog and I cannot see any screen in my Zeplin project.

Here is the error dialog:

[image: Request failed: forbidden (403)]

Note: My sketch app is in its trial period. But it's functioning well, besides this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to [@zeplin_io](https://twitter.com/zeplin_io)'s fast support on Twitter I solved my problem.

Adjusting my Mac's Date & Time Pref.s to Auto solved issue.